# Accessing the DBContext from within an EF CodeFirst Model instance

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an EF4.1 CodeFirst Model instance named Discussion.

I'd like to know how the default "collection property accessors" (e.g. Discussion.messages.get below) get the DB Context managing the current object, because I'd like to write custom accessors that work the same way.

Basically, I want to know how to implement **this.GET_MANAGING_DB_CONTEXT()** in the follow:

```
public class Discussion {

    // The default get; accessor seems to have access to the DBContext
    public virtual ICollection<Message> messages { get; set; }

    // How do I get access to the managing db context myself?
    public ICollection<Monkey> monkeys {
        get {
            return new List<Monkey>(from m in this.GET_MANAGING_DB_CONTEXT().Monkeys select m where m.discussion == this.ID));
        }
    }

    // Here's what I'm forced to do now, which requires passing DBContext around
    // everywhere the object is used, breaking encapsulation of data storage
    public ICollection<Monkey> monkeys(DBContext db) {
        return new List<Monkey>(from m in db.Monkeys...);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question but you seem to be asking to have a filtered set of Monkeys based off the primary key for the current object.

Firstly you shouldn't need the DbContext to do this, Discussion.Id I assume is a PK value and Monkey.discussion is a FK value.

In codefirst I would expect that you would do this

```
public class Discussion {

    public Discussion()
    {
        monkeys = new List<Monkey>();
    }

    ...

    [InverseProperty("discussion")]
    public ICollection<Monkey> monkeys { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Monkey
{
    ...

    [InverseProperty("monkeys")]
    public Discussion discussion { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

This should allow you to reference a filtered set of Monkey based off the value in the discussion field in the monkey table.

If you still need access to the value of the discussion column have a look a the following answer: [Influencing foreign key column naming in EF code first (CTP5)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082991/25372)

Comment: Lets say I wanted to do an arbitrary filtering of the members in code.... Basically, I can't express a whole set of complicated constraints as SQL, so I'd like to use C# to do an SQL query, and then do a bunch of processing on the results....