# Entity Framework 5 Key naming with code first

Tags: c#, code-generation, entity-framework-5

I can't have [.] (periods) in my key names (Indexes, primary keys and foreign keys) when they are generated by Add-Migration, so I tried to write a CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to allow you to change the foreign keys or index names. The primary key name can be set as part of overriding the create table:

```
protected override void Generate(
    CreateTableOperation createTableOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.Name = "USE THIS NAME";
        base.Generate(createTableOperation, writer);
    }
```

But what I really need is a way to ensure that it has just removed full stop (which implies overriding the custom name generator) - but I can't see how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried using the column name attribute as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082991/influencing-foreign-key-column-naming-in-ef-code-first-ctp5

Comment: If you want detailed control over the database. Database first might be a better solution then code first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you not tried retrospectively generating code first with the [power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)?

Not only would it generate code first classes for you from the database, you can also customize the T4 templates that generate your objects in order to handle unique scenarios (for example custom naming logic to handle reserved characters). My entity.tt has the following above each generated object:-

```
[MetadataType(typeof(<#= efHost.EntityType.Name #>_Validation))]
```

This means I can have all my data validation farmed off into a separate class that isn't overridden upon re-creation of my objects.

Comment: Thanks - this issue no longer exists and was quite specific at the time. Things have moved on with tooling over the last year and therefore isn't really relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

this issue no longer exists and was quite specific at the time. Things have moved on with tooling over the last year and therefore isn't really relevant anymore as you wouldn't need to solve the issue this way.

Many thanks for reading and commenting

Answer (score 0):

by entity framework code first migration you can change the foreign keys or index names, you can see in the example in here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=889