# ASP.NET MVC use the same complex type as a property more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a model which uses a class called `Operator` twice, once named `CreatedBy` and once again named `ModifiedBy`. When I create identity fields for these properties EF creates new Identity fields.

```
public int CreatedBy_OperatorId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Created By")]
public virtual Operator CreatedBy { get; set; }

public int ModifiedBy_OperatorId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Created By")]
public virtual Operator ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

My question is how can I force EF to use my Identity fields?

Comment: are you using Fluent Api?

Comment: Where do you create the identity fields? Also show us that code please.

Comment: ModifiedBy_OperatorId is the identity field for ModifiedBy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Influencing foreign key column naming in EF code first (CTP5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082991/influencing-foreign-key-column-naming-in-ef-code-first-ctp5) seems to have the answer.

In code first I need to ensure I have the foreign key specified and then I can define the name of the key using the HasColumnName function.

```
        builder.Entity<ContactRecord>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatedBy_OperatorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        builder.Entity<ContactRecord>()
            .Property(p => p.CreatedBy_OperatorId)
            .HasColumnName("CreatedBy_OperatorId");

        builder.Entity<ContactRecord>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.ModifiedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ModifiedBy_OperatorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        builder.Entity<ContactRecord>()
            .Property(p => p.ModifiedBy_OperatorId)
            .HasColumnName("ModifiedBy_OperatorId");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public int CreatedBy_OperatorId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Created By")]
[ForeignKey("CreatedBy_OperatorId")]
public virtual Operator CreatedBy { get; set; }

public int ModifiedBy_OperatorId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Created By")]
[ForeignKey("ModifiedBy_OperatorId")]
public virtual Operator ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

Comment: Apologies I am using .Net 4 and so don't think I have access to all of the DataAnnotation properties.

Comment: @AndyLord what is the EF version?

Comment: I am using 6.0 in my Persistence project and my MVC project but not in the Class Library.

Comment: Yep, upgrade to 4.5 would be the only option