# How to make Entity Framework use table names instead of class names when naming foreign keys?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

If I have the following model:

```
[Table("Person")]
public class PersonDao
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

[Table("Address")]
public class AddressDao
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public PersonDao Person { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Entity Framework uses `Person` and `Address` correctly for the table names but the foreign key in `Address` is called `PersonDao_Id`. I want it to be `Person_Id`.

Is this a bug or am I supposed to write a custom convention for the property names?

NOTE: I use MySQL with Entity Framework, I don't know if that matters.

**EDIT:** I know that I can specify the column name manually using the `ForeignKey` attribute or the fluent API. I need this to work automatically and globally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148662/mapping-a-foreign-key-with-a-custom-column-name might be usefull

Comment: [ForeignKey("Person_Id")] and details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082991/influencing-foreign-key-column-naming-in-ef-code-first-ctp5

Answer (score 2):

Use attributes just like you did to have different names for the table and class:

```
[Table("Address")]
public class AddressDao
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person_Id")] 
    public PersonDao Person { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

If you don't want to use the default convention you could just remove `Dao` from your class names:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but my question wasn't clear enogh. I already know about this. I need this to work automatically and globally.

Comment: So you're OK with using attributes to specify a table name but not a column name? Why not just name your classes without the `"Dao"`?  To answer the question I do not know of a way to globally override the default convention.

Comment: I like to name my data access classes `Dao` to differentiate them from my domain classes (which have a structure that cannot be directly mapped using EF).

Comment: The difference is that I think foreign key names should contain the table name (either generated from the class name of specified explicitly using an attribute or the fluent API) instead of the class name *by default*. I shouldn't need to specify them explicitly. I actually think that is a subtle bug in EF but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want make your own name of column in database, you can use [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx) in `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method in your database context. Add to your DAO class properties with column name.

```
[Table("Person")]
public class PersonDao
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

[Table("Address")]
public class AddressDao
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid MyPersonDaoColumnName { get; set; }
    public PersonDao Person { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

and then in Fluent API write:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AddressDao>().HasRequired(x => x.Person)
                                     .WithMany(x => x.Addresses)
                                     .HasForeignKey(x => x.MyPersonDaoColumnName);
}
```

but it is ugly to mix Fluent API with Attribute so you need also:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AddressDao>.ToTable("Address");
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDao>.ToTable("Person");
```